# Is valid inference possible after a model improvement suggested by model checking?

Tags: inference, model-selection, selectiveinference

### Scenario

Consider the following scenario in which you have some data $\mathcal D = \{(X_i,Y_i)\}_{i = 1,2,\dots, N}$ and a candidate model $M$ (for instance, for the conditional distribution $\text {Pr}(Y \vert X) = f_M(X,Y)$).

You know the functional form of $f_M$ from previous studies, or perhaps you have selected it from an independent dataset $\mathcal D '$. Your present goal is to fit $f_M$ to the new dataset and perform some inference (say on the parameters that define $f_M$).

You fit $f_M$ to the new dataset $\mathcal D$ and, after some model checking (e.g. checking residuals), you find out that your data violates some basic assumption of the original model $M$ - perhaps the $XY$ distribution has changed, or perhaps $M$ was not so well-specified to begin with.

Moreover, the violation also suggests a new model $M'$ (functional form $f_{M'}\neq f_M$), that seems to perform much better on $\mathcal D$. At this point, you would like to fit the new $f_{M'}$ to the dataset $\mathcal D$ and perform inference within this improved model.

To make things concrete: imagine you are fitting Ohm's law $V = RI$ on experimental data collected on Mars, and your model checks show that, on Mars, $V = RI + \kappa I ^4$. You now want to provide confidence intervals for $R$ and $\kappa$.

---

### The issue

The improved model $M^\prime$ is a random object that depends on the data $\mathcal D$, which in general invalidates any naive inference that treats $M'$ as if it was fixed in advance. This is the usual problem of Selective Inference.

However, there is a complication here with respect to the usual setting of Selective Inference: the concrete improvement $M \to M'$ was suggested by the data, but there was no a-priori fixed family of possible models - the space of possible choices $\mathcal M $ has an unknown (and somewhat hard to define) cardinality.

---

### Questions

Does any formalism exist, which is able to deal with complex and ill-defined situations of this kind (if only putting loose bounds for some special cases)? Otherwise, what best practices would you recommend when reporting this kind of results?